# How Can I Convert Postscript Type 1 font to .otf or .ttf?

Tags: fonts, type-conversion

I have googled until blue in the fingers. I have a Postscript font that I need to use on a website. I need to convert it to .ttf or .otf format. None of the free conversion tools allow .pfm, .afm, or .inf extensions as inputs.

I have tried to install Font Forge with no success. Macports is awful and there are no longer Binaries being published. Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: Question to convert in reverse direction: [How to convert the OTF font to win Type1 font (Pfb) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332755/how-to-convert-the-otf-font-to-win-type1-font-pfb)

Comment: Side note if it's available in metafont maybe [fonts - Script for using metatype to convert metafont to TTF? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148401/script-for-using-metatype-to-convert-metafont-to-ttf) can work too ■ Reverse direction: [How do I use TrueType Fonts with PDFTeX using otftotfm? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm)

Answer (score 36):

For Mac and Windows you can use [TransType](http://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/).

Mac-only solution is [FontXChange](http://fontgear.net/fontxchange.html).

Comment: Just tried TransType 4 with Noto Sans CJK (a new Chinese Font by Google), and it makes a bit of a mess (Dec 2016)

Answer (score 12):

[FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io) seems to be a gross looking, but functional open source tool if you have more time than money.

Comment: ..too close to home for you?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe's [Font Development Kit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html) is a free download available for the Mac and Windows. It has tools that can convert older font files to Opentype.

Comment: It doesn't look like the Font Dev Kit can convert PS Type 1 fonts to anything else, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

http://everythingfonts.com/ps-to-ttf

First rename your post script files add .ps to your file name as an extension, noticed that the file type will change from LWFN to PS

Then Add this .ps file and convert it to ttf

It works perfectly on mine :)

Answer (score 0):

**FontXChange** for Mac and Windows: http://fontgear.net/fontxchange.html